# Simple database setup for MALDI peaks

Tags: database

I have a very simple problem that I could come up with a crude solution to, but it seems to me that there is probably some off the shelf answer.

**Problem:** I have a list of discrete values (these are mass units) that I want to find within a database of discrete values (known mass units) and their identities, allowing for some inexact match. Example: If I am looking for 500.23 in the database then anything +/- 0.025 would be considered a match (50 ppm or 0.005%). This tolerance should be adjustable. So in this example, 500.23 may return the database text value, 500.25 which is Compound A.

I could also make this tool myself if someone would like to suggest the most straightforward approach. I am competent in Matlab, somewhat in R, good in excel, poor in access, and don't know anything about SQL. Best case would be for this tool to be used by non-coders.

**Background:** The real background of this problem is that I have MALDI TOF data where I have identified peaks of interest from an experiment (masses; m/z). These masses correspond to molecules that were released after enzymatic digestion. This class of molecule has reported masses with known identities, but unlike peptide mass fingerprinting, or metabolomic databases, these known masses are mostly unpublished and/or uncollated, so I would like to cross-reference them with a database of my own making. Each mass corresponds to one identity. The masses will not match exactly, and being able to search with a specified mass tolerance is key.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of mass spectrometer data solutions you may want to look at. For example: http://www.ionsource.com/links/programs.htm

Comment: I appreciate your help, but unfortunately I am already familiar with those tools. I am looking to create a simple database to query masses against. This would be most closely related to a metabolomic or lipidomic database, but I want to populate the database with my curated data. Ion source is a great reference, and I do appreciate you taking the time to provide an answer.